# What terminal should i open to run commands to fix permission denied error in php?

Tags: php

I found the solution to fix "fopen(document.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\Project\makePDF.php on line 8". It was suggested that to open terminal and run the command

**sudo chmod filename.php**

But i don't know which terminal should I open to run this command?

Please help me. 
I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: That is a linux command and you are using windows.

Comment: give  read write permission to the file

Answer (score 0):

Windows security settings is preventing you to access that file which is in program Files folder.

1. First method
   You should note that The DocumentRoot and Directory directive directory should match. Your vhosts file inside apache->conf->extra should have the proper directory listing

```html
<Directory "C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\Project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

2. Install XAMPP in C Drive itself like C:/VertrigoServ instead of C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\ . Program Files Directory require special permissions.

Comment: I tried but still not working throwing the same error all the time

Answer (score 0):

1)Right click the folder, click on Properties.

2)Click on the Security tab

3)Add the name Everyone to the user list.

Comment: Can you please describe it in detail because I am trying to change to change permission but its coming blurred not allowing me to do any change